# Синтаксис, словосочетание

Tags: синтаксис

Какой вопрос задается к словосочетанию *туристы из Японии*?

Answer (score 2):

Туристы (какие? откуда?) из Японии, это обстоятельственное определение. Туристы из Японии остановились в гостинице.

Сравнить: Туристы приехали  (откуда?) из Японии. Это обстоятельство.

Answer (score 0):

Общие вопросы, требующие полного ответа "Туристы из Японии":

> Кто? Кто это? Кто эти люди? Кто они?

Уточняющие вопросы, когда полный ответ "Туристы из Японии" возможен, но не обязателен, и предпочтительно ответить "Из Японии" или "Туристы".

> Туристы откуда? Из какой страны туристы? Кто из Японии?